# Update constraints with UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a black separatorView in the middle of the screen separating a topContainerView (orange) and a bottomContainerView (green). The separatorView can be dragged up and down with a panGesture, but I can't get the top and bottom views to update their constraints and resize. The bottom of the orange view and the top of the green view should always stick with the separatorView.

Here's the code I have (UPDATED to include variable declarations):

```html
let separatorView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

let topContainerView : UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

let bottomContainerView : UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.addViews()
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(detectPan(recognizer:)))
        panGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = false
        panGesture.delaysTouchesEnded = false
        separatorView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
    func addViews() {
        
        view.addSubview(topContainerView)
        view.addSubview(bottomContainerView)
        view.addSubview(separatorView)
        
        separatorView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        separatorView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        separatorView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        separatorView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        
        topContainerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        topContainerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        topContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        topContainerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: separatorView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        
        bottomContainerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomContainerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: separatorView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        bottomContainerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    func detectPan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
        separatorView.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: lastLocation.y + translation.y)
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: separatorView)
        lastLocation = separatorView.center
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you set your views' `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`?

Comment: I did, for each view

Comment: where did you do it? I don't see it in your code

Comment: Have you tried to re-layout the subviews? *view.layoutIfNeeded*. Your code looks good. But it seems like the *other* views aren't being told to be laid out again.

Comment: Just updated the code to show those variables declared. Already tried putting view.layoutIfNeeded in detectPan and touchesBegan, didn't make a difference.

Comment: Don't modify the separator view `center` property, modify the `constanf` property of the separator's CenterY constraint. Autolayout will do the rest.

Comment: One more time - in your detectPan, have you tried to update the layout?

Comment: @dfd that won't work since Autolayout will just put the separator back where the constraints say it should be; in the center.  When you are using autolayout you can't mess with the frame directly; you have to manipulate the constraints

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you are using Autolayout you can't simply modify the frame of elements (which is what you are doing implicitly by changing the `center` property).  Well, you can, but it won't affect any other elements (as you have found) and as soon as Autolayout is triggered your changes to the frame will be reset.

You need to manipulate the constraints so that Autolayout produces the result you want.

In this case you need to modify the `constant` property of your constraint that ties the separator to the center of the view.  You can use the translation value of the pan gesture recognizer to do this.  The only tricky bit is that this translation is relative to 0 at the start of the pan, so you need to incorporate any offset from any previous pan.

```
let separatorView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

let topContainerView : UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

let bottomContainerView : UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

var centerConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

var startingConstant: CGFloat  = 0.0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.addViews()
    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(detectPan(recognizer:)))
    panGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = false
    panGesture.delaysTouchesEnded = false
    separatorView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func addViews() {

    view.addSubview(topContainerView)
    view.addSubview(bottomContainerView)
    view.addSubview(separatorView)

    separatorView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    separatorView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true

    self.centerConstraint = separatorView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
    self.centerConstraint.isActive = true

    separatorView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

    topContainerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    topContainerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    topContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    topContainerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: separatorView.topAnchor).isActive = true

    bottomContainerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    bottomContainerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    bottomContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: separatorView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    bottomContainerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}

func detectPan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    switch recognizer.state {
    case .began:
        self.startingConstant = self.centerConstraint.constant
    case .changed:
        let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
        self.centerConstraint.constant = self.startingConstant + translation.y
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, this is what I ended up doing. Modifying the center wasn't updating anything else. Had to modify the centerYAnchor constant. Thanks!

Comment: Ohh this is awesome! Thanks! In my case I just assigned the `recognizer.translation(in: self.view).y` value as the constant value of the constraint and wondered all the time why my view jumps around..